# Superbugs in eusocial animals

Tags: zoology, bacteriology, infectious-diseases, antibiotics, eusociality

I am not a biologist, and I'm interested in eusocial animals, and the porous habitats in which they live. I know few facts about diseases in these animals: I know some interesting instances of viruses, bugs and about cancer, respectively [1] in Spanish, the hygroscopic property of honey (I don't know the article [2]), and [3].

**Question.** I would like to know if there are eusocial animals which suffer diseases due to superbugs. In such case add the most relevant facts from your knowledges or cite/refer the most relevant articles from the literature.

I add as general references that Wikipedia have edited the article [*Eusociality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusociality) and [*Antimicrobial resistance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_resistance) redirected from the search Superbug (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bug). I hope that my question does make sense (for some eusocial species), in other case I can to delete my post. Feel free to add your feedback in comments if my post isn't suitable for your site Biology Stack Exchange.

### References:

[1] David Pride, *Los virus de nuestro cuerpo*, Investigación y Ciencia, Febrero 2021, Nº 533, pages. 76-83.

[2] Manisha Deb Mandal and Shyamapada Mandal, *Honey: its medicinal property and antibacterial activity*, Asian Pac J Trop Biomed. 2011 Apr; 1(2): pages 154–160.

[3] Elizabeth Pennisi, *Why Naked Mole Rats Don't Get Cancer*, from the web of Science (19 Jun 2013).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on what we do here and what makes a good question and answer. In particular, have a look at the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) section and see how that applies to your question. As it stands there is little linking your statement in para 1 to the question and the references to cancer and honey don't seem appropriate given that these have nothing to do with superbugs.

Comment: If I understand right, you are considering the antibacterial properties of honey to be similar to antibiotics, considering other eusocial animals may produce anti-pathogen substances, and asking if pathogens that resist these substances cause disease in the eusocial animals. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I don't assert it, and I'm sorry @timeskull if I've introduced a misunderstanding with my references. The references cited [1], [2] are to illustrate that I know that some eusocial animals suffer infections/ diseases caused (respectively) by viruses and bacteria, and that the case of cancer was studied in the mammals in [3]. I would like to know if there is some eusocial animals that suffer disesas causes by superbugs. Many thanks and I hope don't bother you or your colleagues (professors of the site).

Comment: Well, a "superbug" is a pathogen that is resistant to antibiotics or antifungals. No eusocial animals produce those so resistance wouldn't affect them.

Comment: Not an answer because I can't give a definitive yes/no to eusocial animals. Well, human to dog transfer of MRSA has been [recorded in 2004](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/10/12/04-0387_article), and although dogs/wolves are not technically eusocial, it would indicate a first step in the transmission to non-human animals. [Superbugs in livestock](https://foodtank.com/news/2021/06/squashing-superbugs-in-the-livestock-industry/) are a matter of great concern too.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments @JiminyCricket. and for your colleagues